# Extend com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeaderBuilder

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, materialdrawer

I need to build my own AccountHeaderBuilder implementation.

So I'm trying to extend a class from [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library.
In Android studio, how do I need to proceed in order to do that?
Should MaterialDrawer library be imported as a module?

If yes, why do I get errors like:
`Error:(1290) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'MaterialTheme'.` when I import the project as a module...

Even when my gradle is set to :

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
  minSdkVersion 15
  targetSdkVersion 23
```

My class extending AccountHeaderBuilder needs to be in the same package... So my understanding is that I cannot just use in the gradle file.

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.0.9@aar')
```

**So, in one sentence : how to I proceed to be able to extend classes from another project?**

Thanks a lot for the help

ps: I have been able to integrate this library and make it work in my project but now I need extra funcionalities.

Comment: Why do you need to extend the `AccountHeaderBuilder`? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to : 1: remove totally the icon for each profile.
2 : add additional information (better said TextView) below the Profile Name or email. Like for example:
greg@gmail.com
2 Kids
Married

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs because the required dependencies are missing. The MaterialDrawer depends on the [Materialize](https://github.com/mikepenz/Materialize) and [FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter) libraries which provide required helper classes.

The documentation of the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) states to add `transitive=true` which will automatically resolve the sub dependencies of the `MaterialDrawer`

So replace your compile statement with:

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.1.4@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

---

As of the requirement mentioned in the comment. 
It is also possible to overwrite the layout used for the `AccountHeader` https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/res/layout/material_drawer_header.xml

You can alter that layout to anything you want, just remember the `id`s which are in need to stay the same, and you can't remove existing views like the profiles, but you could just alter it so the `ImageView`s are within a layout, and set this one to `gone`. So the profiles won't be visible anymore.

For the additional row. You can add this one to the `selection` container where the existing two `TextView`s are included. After that you just listen for the `onProfileChanged` event from the `AccountHeaderBuilder`, and update this `TextView` when the profile changes.

(You can get this view by searching for it with `findViewById` on the `AccountHeader` container view https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/AccountHeader.java#L38)

Comment: Yes, I have that added, the problem I have occurs when I try to add the project as a Module.

Comment: if you add it as module, you will have to add all sub dependencies to your project. See my updated answer,  how you could achieve your requirement without the need of adding the library as module. It has also an additional advantage, as it will still allow you to retrieve updates from the official repo

Comment: Thanks for the help Mike.  Will try that right now :) And thanks a lot for the amazing job done with that library of yours ;)